# High memory usage when calling to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem.I have saved images in the core data.I have a `TableView` and in every cell of that table I have an image,which loads from the core data.

**Here are codes.**

**In this part of my code,I get data for images for every cell**

```
   if let img = CoreDataFunctions.loadImageFromCache(imgURL){
                cell.PersonImage?.image = UIImage(data:img)
            }
```

**It is** `CoreDataFunctions.loadImageFromCache` **method**

```
class func loadImageFromCache(selfiePath:String?) -> NSData? {
        let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Images")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "selfie == %@", selfiePath!)

        if let fetchResults = try! managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Images] {
            if fetchResults.count == 1 {
                return fetchResults[0].imageData
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

When I finish the loading of the images, the Memory Usage becomes too high and stays on that position.Can anyone tell me the reason ???

Comment: Hi. Is a memory freeing after how you close your controller with images?

Comment: I dont close it,its in rootController,I can only navigate to other controllers with show modally segues and go back with dismissViewControllerAnimated function

Comment: I guess the managedObjects are still alive. Try a reset on the managedObjectContext to verify if it's that. But you shouldn't store images in core data, it make the database bigger, and in a automigration, the database is first copy then updated, if you do it on startup, it can take too much time and your app can be killed by the system.

Comment: But if i have a ,lets say 1000 images,and every image about 100 kb it will take from RAM 100mb its too much

Comment: If you have a `UITableView`.. it's mean that you can show about 10-20 cells on the screen. When you scrolls a your `tableView` the new cells will be added to the screen and old cells will be dismissed. You should not load all images at once. It is should be a  fetch 'on-demand'.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the images in a table view. You will then have a significantly lower memory footprint. You can also eliminate your expensive fetch method.

2) Check "External Storage" for your data attribute in the model editor to make sure the images are **not actually stored in the database**. Alternatively, devise your own storage/naming scheme and store the images in the applications documents directory.